# RHEL: FDE w/o password - boot from key on partition

Tags: rhel, lvm, encryption, luks

I'm trying to accomplish encrypting my OS w/ LVM on RHEL 7.2 and have it boot without entering a password by using a key on an unencrypted partition.

```
 LV    VG    Attr     LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
 home rhel -wi-ao---- 22.35g                                                 
 root rhel -wi-ao---- 27.94g                                                 
 swap rhel -wi-ao----  1.86g
```

I created an unencrypted mount point `/media` where I generated a key using the following commands:

```
dd bs=512 count=4 if=/dev/urandom of=/media/fdekey iflag=fullblock
```

I added the key with my passphrase as follows:

```
 cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/mapper/rhel-root /media/fdekey
 cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/mapper/rhel-home /media/fdekey
 cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/mapper/rhel-swap /media/fdekey
```

I then edited `/etc/crypttab` to add the key:

```
luks-b7ac522a-52fd-4540-917d-3454dafdf7dc UUID=b7ac522a-52fd-4540-917d-3454dafdf7dc /media/fdekey luks
luks-ad431e02-a49d-4ba3-bf9c-06e7a9f9a7f9 UUID=ad431e02-a49d-4ba3-bf9c-06e7a9f9a7f9 /media/fdekey luks
luks-a3819933-91d5-434b-bb6c-42d273bb34c2 UUID=a3819933-91d5-434b-bb6c-42d273bb34c2 /media/fdekey luks
```

Modified `/etc/dracut.conf`

```
# dracut modules to omit
omit_dracutmodules+="systemd"

# dracut modules to add to the default
add_dracutmodules+="crypt lvm"
```

Modified `/etc/default/grub`:

```
rd.luks.key=/media/fdekey:LABEL=media
```

Generated grub:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Generated initramfs:

`dracut -fv`

output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-3        28G  876M   28G   4% /
devtmpfs        9.6G     0  9.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           9.6G     0  9.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           9.6G  8.4M  9.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           9.6G     0  9.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       4.5G   19M  4.2G   1% /media
/dev/sda1       950M  133M  818M  14% /boot
/dev/dm-5        23G   33M   23G   1% /home
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/user/0
```

output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 64.4 GB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a0a6e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1953791      975872   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1953792    11718655     4882432   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        11718656   121114623    54697984   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-root: 30.0 GB, 30001856512 bytes, 58597376 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-swap: 2000 MB, 2000683008 bytes, 3907584 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-b7ac522a-52fd-4540-917d-3454dafdf7dc: 1998 MB, 1998585856 bytes, 3903488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-a3819933-91d5-434b-bb6c-42d273bb34c2: 30.0 GB, 29999759360 bytes, 58593280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-home: 24.0 GB, 23999807488 bytes, 46874624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-ad431e02-a49d-4ba3-bf9c-06e7a9f9a7f9: 24.0 GB, 23997710336 bytes, 46870528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**I feel like I'm missing some step(s). Upon boot up I am still asked for the passphrase.**

Comment: Did you recreate your initramfs?

Comment: I did not, what are the steps to rebuild it in RHEL for crypttab? I can only find instructions for non red hat based systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add the path to my keyfile to `dracut.conf`and rebuild initramfs.

```
echo 'install_items+="/media/key"' >> /etc/dracut.conf
dracut -fv
```

Comment: Sounds like the key is just copied to initramfs.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to recreate initramfs after modifying your disk configuration. To recreate it in RHEL 6/7 just run as root

```
dracut --force
```

Comment: I ran the `dracut --force` command but I am still prompted for the password on bootup.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10750983